# 'Hash#keys' in helper

Tags: ruby

I have this method in helper:

```
def get_hash_keys(hash)
  hash.delete_if{|k, v| v.class != Hash}
  return hash.keys
end
```

When I call `get_hash_keys` from another method in the same helper, it returns a blank array :

```
def datas_size
  sum = 0
  new_hash = {title: "This is a test", datas: {firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar"}}
  new_hash.each do |k, v|
    sum += v.size if get_hash_keys(new_hash).includes? k
  end

  return sum
end
```

I tested to change `return hash.keys` with fixed array, and I get it. Only `keys` function seems not to work. I also double checked my array in params.

Is there some specifications I ignore working inside helpers ?

Edit for @DRSE :

I start with hash that contains others hashes. I need to know size of each children hash. The point is when I call this function (get_hash_keys) from the views, it fails (return blank array), but from console it works (return keys).

More investigation this morning drive me to conclude may be this is a wrong usage of delete_if. My ununderstood solution is to replace :

```
def get_hash_keys(hash)
  hash.delete_if{|k, v| v.class != Hash}
  return hash.keys
end
```

with

```
def get_hash_keys(hash)
  tmp_hash = hash.clone
  tmp_hash.delete_if{|k, v| v.class != Hash}
  return tmp_hash.keys
end
```

Comment: What is wrong? You tell us, not the other way around.

Comment: I should get keys of hash in param, not blank array...

Comment: I think I'd better post full example, without dots. And show data you are testing with

Comment: Is `display_keys` relevant in any way to your question? If not, please remove it. Show the minimal example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: `"foo " + get_new_keys(hash)` is invalid. It produces *"TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String"*

Comment: Ok, eddited according your comments. I hope it's more clean. @axiac, I was wrong during simplification, sorry :)

Comment: `get_hash_keys` takes one argument, but you are passing no arguments to it.

Comment: @sawa: yeah, and there is at least one other error too. Not to mention they mutate `new_hash` while iterating it.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you are starting from (seems like maybe you start with a `Hash` with some information) and where you would like to get to based on where you started from?  Then also show what you have tried.  Currently, your post shows only what you have tried but you have not indicated your actual question/problem.

Comment: You mutate the original hash and _then_ you clone it? wat?

Comment: Edited. @SergioTulentsev Try to give advice rather than criticize and take people for fools

Comment: @FlorentL.: good point. And you should be posting [mcve] instead of incomplete snippets which you claim as "working incorrectly", but you don't show neither full snippets nor data that they operate on. And on top of it, these snippets can't possibly work at all, because they contain several errors that cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with `hash.keys`:

```
def get_new_keys(hash)
  hash.delete_if{|k,v| k == :bar}
  return hash.keys
end
get_new_keys({qux: :bar, bar: :baz}) # => [:qux]
```

This, on the other hand, is busted.

```
def display_keys(hash)
  return "foo " + get_new_keys(hash)
end
```

Are you expecting an `array` to be returned? If so, that's not the way to go about it at all. You *could* do something like:

```
def display_keys(hash)
  return [:foo].concat(get_new_keys(hash))
end
```

In which case, it'd do something like:

```
def display_keys(hash)
  return [:foo].concat(get_new_keys(hash))
end
display_keys({qux: :bar, bar: :baz}) # => [:foo, :qux]
```

Comment: No worries. For the future, strive to post copy-pastable code. Immensely convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The `.keys` method returns and Array of keys in the Hash.

Your question is impossible to answer for two reasons:

1. You have not included the condition in your `delete_if` block. My
   guess is that you are deleting all keys in the hash, so `.keys` is
   returning `[]`.
2. You have not described the output you are expecting.

On a side note, your method `display_keys` does not work in ruby `2.3`. You cannot concatenate an Array and a String like that. It will throw a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String`

But taking my best guess at it the following code works just fine:

```
def get_new_keys(hash)
    hash.delete_if{ |k,v| v % 2 == 0 }
    return hash.keys
end

def display_keys(hash)
    return ["foo"] + get_new_keys(hash)
end

hash = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4,
    five: 5,
    six: 6,
    seven: 7,
    eight: 8,
    nine: 9,
    ten: 10
}
```

Outputs:

```
pry(main)> display_keys( hash )
=> ["foo", :one, :three, :five, :seven, :nine]
```